# Why is DSU decorate-sort-undecorate faster than providing a compare function?

Tags: python, sorting

Pythonistas like to talk about a technique called DSU:

Suppose I want to sort a list by the third field's int value:

```
# Decorate
decorated = [(int(item[2]), item) for item in items]
# Sort
decorated.sort()
# Undecorate
items = [item[1] for item in decorated]
```

Supposedly, this method is much more efficient than:

```
def compare(item1, item2):
    return cmp(int(item1[2]), int(item2[2]))
items.sort(compare)
```

Why is DSU faster? What makes sort() without a comparator special?

Comment: It is not generally true that DSU is faster. In fact, using a key function is probably faster more generally. A key function does not use `cmp` and `cmp` has been removed in Python 3x

Comment: Yes, I see cmp has been removed in PY3, now I understand why.

Comment: @dawg The `key` argument is essentially built-in support for DSU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how expensive the conversion from an item to value to be sorted by is. In this case, the conversion is to take the `int` of the third item.

With the compare method, the conversion happens multiple times per item. With the decorate/sort/undecorate method, the conversion only happens once per item. If the key function is expensive, then calling it only once per item should be more efficient.

Note that you can do the decorate/sort/undecorate approach with built-ins:

```
items.sort(key=lambda item: int(item[2]))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `cmp` function has to be called repeatedly during the sort, once for each time that the sorter needs to compare two objects.  Since the same object may have to be compared to multiple others during the sort, the `cmp` may be called more than once per object.  Using DSU, on the other hand, only requires executing the decoration code once for each item in the list, no matter how many comparisons are done.

In recent versions of Python, you can use the `key` argument to `sort` instead: `items.sort(key=lambda item: item[2])`.  This effectively does DSU for you.